# How to sort array elements using x-axis values?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Actually I am getting the label values and x-coordinate and I need to sort the label values according to x-coordinate values. Can you please any one give me code how to do it. Thanks in advance..

Comment: How is the information stored in the array? Is it a single array or two arrays?

Comment: Can you tell us the types of elements in the array?  When you say x-axis value, do you mean aView.frame.origin.x, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it, you should be able to do it with keypaths a lot nicer.

```c
[labels sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    return [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[(UIView *)obj1 frame].origin.x] compare:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[(UIView *)obj2 frame].origin.x]];
}];
```